# FutureBuilder not updating UI even after setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am a complete Flutter begginer. When screen loads for initial time, the data is correctly loaded with `getOnlineClass()`  function. But when I try to update the value of UI, the new data is loaded but the UI does not update.

```
 return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        return dataLoader.loadOnlineClass().then((value) => (value){
          print(value);
          listDummy = PersistenceHelper().getOnlineClass();
          setState(() {
            print(listDummy.toString());
          });
        });
      },
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: listDummy, // async work
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              else

                // print(snapshot.data);
                return _listShowerTest(snapshot.data);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a typo.

You have given

```
return dataLoader.loadOnlineClass().then((value) => (value){
```

But you should use it like this.

```
return dataLoader.loadOnlineClass().then((value) {
```

Remove the second `(value)` part, since when you put it there, your are creating a new function which takes a single parameter. Like this `(value) {}`.

So, fixed code will be

```
onRefresh: () {
    return dataLoader.loadOnlineClass().then((value) {
        print(value);
        listDummy = PersistenceHelper().getOnlineClass();
        setState(() {
            // Also you should do some actual state setting here.
            print(listDummy.toString());
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: @npsulav. Check if this fixes your problem.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. What I want is when I refresh, the Widget in the child of that Refresh should completely rebuild itself.

Comment: The Child should've automatically refreshed. Update your question with your full Widget code. Let me see if I ccan help.

Comment: Thanks I did it using Navigator.push()

Comment: How is `Navigator` related to `Refresh`. Consider posting an answer yourself so that it may help others.

Comment: the ```Refresh``` did not worked as intended with ```setState``` so I did ```Navigator.push()``` to the current screen which made it reload. ik this is not best way but i am learning and this became the easiest workaround for me

Comment: Huh, definitely just a hack. Do you want to improve the question ? I will try and fix it so that it. may help others.